# M-d doesn't work in ansi-term

Tags: emacs

Killing a word with M-d in ansi-term doesn't work. It visually kills the word, but when I press enter it still runs the command prior to the word kill. C-k works fine though.

Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're working in `term-line-mode` <kbd>C-c C-j</kbd>, you need to switch to `term-char-mode` <kbd>C-c C-k</kbd>.

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior in term-char-mode too.

Comment: @ednedn: Does it work in the inferior shell (outside Emacs)? char sub-mode of the term mode sends characters directly to it, see `term-raw-map` variable.

Comment: A different package wasn't sending the characters directly to it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this, but isn't the answer back-to-front? `term-line-mode` is the one which enables you to use Emacs' editing commands safely.

Comment: @phils: The order is correct. If `M-d` visually kills the word, but it still there when the command runs: it means `M-d` is not sent to the shell i.e., it could mean that term-line-mode is active (in `term-char-mode` every character except the escape character is sent directly to the shell).

Comment: I guess it can happen both ways, then. I had the opposite experience: subword-mode's `subword-backward-kill` was taking effect in `term-char-mode` and visually deleting characters, but having no effect on the shell (and consequently messing up the command), whereas this wasn't a problem in `term-line-mode`.